# Cloning nodes with relationships in Neo4j with active UUID-plugin

Tags: neo4j, uuid, neo4j-apoc

Need to solve a unusual problem with Neo4j.
We are using UUID-plugin and need to clone a node with all relationships.
I am using expression like this:

```
 ()  . = $
 ..([], , [''])
 
 *
```

Expectedly, if source node had any relationships, neo4j is throwing **Neo.ClientError.Transaction.TransactionHookFailed**, because third argument in apoc procedure demand to skip uuid of node, but unfortunatly not of relationships.

So... what can be a workaround? Thank you.